# How to sum specific columns of a pandas dataframe and then plot the totals on a histogram

Tags: pandas, plot, pycharm, histogram

My dataframe consists of 59 columns with +2000 rows of data (data collected per second). I need to sum/add all data in individual columns 29 to 60, to give 31 bin totals. I then need to plot the 31 bin totals in a histogram with bin number as the x axis and number of counts on the y axis.

NB: I am working in a Function inside a Class called from elsewhere.

I have summed/added each specified column using the sum() function. The histogram function is then called, and it gets as far as producing an empty figure and then produces a long list of errors, culminating at a datetime error (I am not sure how datetime is involved in this...). Please can someone point me in the right direction and help get my histogram working?

The examples shows the preceding code and just the first 5 bins.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Pops(object):
    def __init__(self, popsfile): #, pops_hdr_lines):
        '''
...

        '''
        #________________________________________________
        #         # READ IN FILES AND CONCATENATE FILES 

        if not isinstance(popsfile, list):
            self.POPSfile = [popsfile]
        else:
            self.POPSfile = popsfile

        # read in multiple POPS datafiles into a list
        dfs = []
        for file in self.POPSfile:
            df = pd.read_csv(file, sep=',', header=0) # PANDAS!
            dfs.append(df)

        # concatenate all dataframes together
            data = pd.concat(dfs)

        # ------------------------------------------------------------
        # create new time stamp
        # determine date
        date_string = self.POPSfile[0][-16:-8]  # extracts YYYYMMDD.
        popsdate = dt.datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y%m%d')

        # Convert from date and time in sam since 1/1/1970
        data.DateTime = pd.to_datetime(data.DateTime, errors='coerce', unit='s')

        # Rename columns to remove whitespaces
        data = data.rename(columns={' Status': 'Status', ' PartCt': 'PartCt', ' PartCon': 'PartCon',' BL': 'BL',
                                    ' P': 'P', ' POPS_Flow': 'POPS_Flow', ' LDTemp': 'LDTemp', ' Temp': 'Temp',
                                    ' Laser_Current': 'Laser_Current'})

        self.data = data

    def plot_housekeeping(self, path, show_save):
        '''plot some of the basic data

        '''

        # histogram attempt

        bins = self.data[['b0', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4']].sum() # sums the bins of interest
        print(bins) # check output
        plt.hist(bins)
        plt.show()


        return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is what I get:

```
b0    12965454
b1     9168956
b2     4178861
b3     2878718
b4     2699768
dtype: int64
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/scitools/environments/default/current/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5.py", line 519, in _draw_idle
    self.draw()
  File "/opt/scitools/environments/default/current/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py", line 437, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "/opt/scitools/environments/default/current/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/scitools/environments/default/current/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1493, in draw
    renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
  File "/opt/scitools/environments/default/current/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 141, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/opt/scitools/environments/default/current/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/scitools/environments/default/current/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 2635, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, artists)
  File "/opt/scitools/environments/default/current/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py", line 141, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "/opt/scitools/environments/default/current/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py", line 55, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/scitools/environments/default/current/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1190, in draw
    ticks_to_draw = self._update_ticks(renderer)
  File "/opt/scitools/environments/default/current/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 1028, in _update_ticks
    tick_tups = list(self.iter_ticks())  # iter_ticks calls the locator
  File "/opt/scitools/environments/default/current/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py", line 971, in iter_ticks
    majorLocs = self.major.locator()
  File "/opt/scitools/environments/default/current/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py", line 1249, in __call__
    self.refresh()
  File "/opt/scitools/environments/default/current/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py", line 1269, in refresh
    dmin, dmax = self.viewlim_to_dt()
  File "/opt/scitools/environments/default/current/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py", line 1027, in viewlim_to_dt
    return num2date(vmin, self.tz), num2date(vmax, self.tz)
  File "/opt/scitools/environments/default/current/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py", line 522, in num2date
    return _from_ordinalf(x, tz)
  File "/opt/scitools/environments/default/current/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py", line 322, in _from_ordinalf
    dt = datetime.datetime.fromordinal(ix).replace(tzinfo=UTC)
ValueError: year 37173 is out of range
```

Comment: Hi there! Could you please reformat your code so it's a little bit easier to read?

Comment: The formatting looks OK now - any better?